# How to specifically select item from a list with index information and assign them to library

Tags: python, list

I am working on a function to exclude all occurrences in a list and return a tuple/list with index information that will be assigned to a library. For example:

for a list input:

```
x = [0,0,1,2,3,0,0,]
```

output:

```
{"inds":[2,3,4],"vals":[1,2,3]}
```

My current solution is very ungly:

```
def function(x):
    b = list()
    c = list()
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
    a = list(enumerate(x))
    for i in a:
        if i[1]!=0:
            b.append(i[1])
            c.append(i[0])
    d["inds"] = c
    d["vals"] = b
    return d
```

I am looking forward a concise solution.

Comment: "I am working on a function to exclude all occurrences in a list" <- All occurences of *what*?

Comment: In my case, it is "0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically there, you have the concept in mind. There's just a few ways to clean up your code.

There's no need to create lists b and c, when you can simply append the new data into the dictionary:

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
for i, j in enumerate(x):
    if j != 0:
        d['inds'].append(i)
        d['vals'].append(j)
print(d)
# Prints: {'vals': [1, 2, 3], 'inds': [2, 3, 4]}
```

There's also no need to call `list()` around `enumerate()`. I'm going to assume you use Python 3 here and that when you do `enumerate()`, you see something like:

```
<enumerate object at 0x102c579b0>
```

This is ok! This is because `enumerate` returns a special object of its own which is iterable just like a list, so you can simply loop through `a`. Also, since the list will have two values per item, you can do `for i, j` like I have.

Comment: Instead of `if j != 0` you could also use the shorter `if j`

Comment: @MSeifert That is true, yes. I like to do j != 0 since it's nice and readable :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also like this:

```
d = dict((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(x) if v)
d = {'inds': d.keys(), 'vals': d.values()}
```

**EDIT:**

If order matters, then like this (thanks to comments):

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(x) if v)
d = {'inds': d.keys(), 'vals': d.values()}
```

Comment: Just that they won't be ordered (because `d` is unordered)

Comment: Use an `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

```
idx, vals = zip(*[[n, v] for n, v in enumerate(x) if v])
d = {"inds": idx, "vals": vals}
>>> d
{'inds': [2, 3, 4], 'vals': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok, but you have some superfluous lines.

```
def function(x):
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
    for index, value in enumerate(x):
        if value != 0:
            d['inds'].append(index)
            d['vals'].append(value)
    return d
```

If performance is an issue for very long arrays you could also use numpy:

```
def function(x):
    x_arr = np.array(x)
    mask = x_arr != 0
    indices = np.argwhere(mask)[:,0]
    values = x_arr[mask]
    return {'inds': list(indices), 'vals': list(values)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by this ugly functional one-liner:

```
{'inds': list(filter(lambda x: x>0, map(lambda (i,x): i if x>0 else 0 , enumerate(x)))), 'vals': list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, x))}
```

output:

```
{'inds': [2, 3, 4], 'vals': [1, 2, 3]}
```

this gives you inds:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x>0, map(lambda (i,x): i if x>0 else 0 , enumerate(x))))
```

this gives you values:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, x))
```

Comment: This is inefficient, because you're iterating through `x` more than once unnecessarily

Comment: yes but he wanted more concise, not more efficient:)

Comment: Thanks, I will need more time to digest your line.